# Is there any way to use c++ in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to use c++ binary in chrome extension ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, like with other browsers, you can write a NPAPI plugin that will comunicate with your extension.

See a generic description [at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI)

Comment: Then why not write it directly as a NPAPI in the first place?

Answer (score 45):

NPAPI was deprecated from Chrome/Opera for security concerns.

You can still use NPAPI if you are targeting firefox, but if Firefox follows the trend it might disable it at some point as well.

The better options you have today are

### Use NaCl if you are targeting only Chrome

You can use instead [NativeClient](http://code.google.com/chrome/nativeclient/) (A.K.A. NaCL, A.K.A. PPAPI - Pepper Plugin API)

All code ran inside NaCl is sandboxed so it's as secure as a javascript extensions.

### Use asm.js if you targeting all Platforms

Using [Emscripten](http://emscripten.org) you can compile C/C++ code into highly optimized javascript format called asm.js. It is designed to have near native performance and right now has [decent support from grade-A browsers except Safari](http://caniuse.com/asmjs). Though performance is better in Firefox than Chrome at the moment.

Major browser vendors are also working on a new standard called WebAssembly that is partially inspired by asm.js, but not ready for prime usage as of this article

## Update 2018-05-14

Native Client is being deprecated and asm.js is being replaced by [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org/) which is becoming the new standard to compile C++ code for the web.

Comment: What is the browser support for PPAPI? Is it a Chrome-only thing and hence has little chance of being utilized by other browsers in the future?

Comment: PPAPI is also supported by Opera since it's now based on Chrome.

Comment: Note that NPAPI is not much better, it's only supported by Safari/Firefox at this point since neither IE or Chrome support it anymore.
IE used ActiveX which was also deprecated for Microsoft Edge. Building native browser plugins is not something easily doable cross-browser I guess.

Comment: can you expand on your update? any URL out there with any manual on how to develop a browser extension with WASM?

Answer (score 0):

As said upper, you can use NaCl for chrome and asm.js with Emscripten for all platforms, but it's reverse engineering is simpler, than binary. Now There is a middle solution: webassembly - LLVM bytecode embeded in browser is supported by most modern browsers https://caniuse.com/#feat=wasm .
So Emscripten can compile C++ to wasm, mostly it's faster than asm.js.