# Use node modues that contain cpp code in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to load [node-cld](https://github.com/dachev/node-cld), a node module that also contains .cc files that are compiled to .node file.

As I want to run this code as a chrome extension, I can only use javascript files.

Is there a possible way to convert such code to be only JS?

Comment: bundle it into a folder with your `manifest.json`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to use c++ in chrome extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666957/is-there-any-way-to-use-c-in-chrome-extension)